# Express or react is removing headers

Tags: reactjs, express

I have a simple react and express setup. I'm adding headers to a response but not all of them are available in the react app.

In Express...

```
app.post('/api/createpdf', (req, res) => {        
    console.log("Handling...");

    let absoluteFilePath = ...

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=test');
    res.setHeader('a', 'b');
    res.setHeader('Content-types', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('c', 'd');

    var filestream = fs.createReadStream(absoluteFilePath);
    filestream.pipe(res);
}
```

In react...

```
createPdf_onClick() {

    console.log("Creating PDF...");

    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/createpdf`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "a": "b",
                "c": "d"})})
        .then(response => {
                console.log("Headers...");
                response.headers.forEach((v, k, p) => {
                    console.log("k: " + k + ", v: " + v);
                });
                console.log("done");

        });
}
```

Console output...

```
App.js:38 Headers...
App.js:40 k: content-type, v: application/pdf
App.js:42 done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`** response header indicates which
>   headers can be exposed as part of the response by listing their names.
>
> By default, only the 6 simple response headers are exposed:
>
> - Cache-Control
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type
> - Expires
> - Last-Modified
> - Pragma
>
> If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to
>   list them using the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

[Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)